# Popping/clicking noise from road bike

Tags: road-bike, noise, clicking

first posting here. I bought a second hand Madone 4.5 which makes this weird popping/clicking noise on a few gears, here’s a [video](https://youtu.be/7v_XfSMb5-M) to better describe. This happens on my stand or while riding. I noticed that the noise might be from the bottom pulley trying to grab on the spokes...

**What I’ve done so far:**

- Clean and lube the chain, pulleys, front and rear derailleurs.
- Changed shifter cables to Dura ace with polymer.
- Indexed and adjusted shifting.

**Bike components:**

It’s a 10 speed Madone 4.5 with an 11 speed cassette.

- Shifter: ST-5603 Shimano 105
- Rear derailleur: RD-6700 Shimano Uletgra
- Cassette: CS-R7000 Shimano 105
- Front derailleur: Shimano 105 FD-5700
- Chain: HG CN-6701 Shimano Ultegra

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Sounds to me like the derailer is slightly misadjusted, so the chain is trying to "climb" to the next larger cog.  A slight tweak of the cable tension adjuster should fix this.

Comment: "It's a 10 speed Madone 4.5 with an 11 speed cassette"  How was this supposed to ever work?     You have a 10 speed shifter and a 10 speed derailleur with an 11 speed cassette, that's your problem.  Change to 10 speed throughout or 11 speed throughout.

Comment: Thank you for this :)

Answer (score 6):

You have a Shimano 105 5603 series 10 speed shifter paired with a Ultegra 6700 series 10 speed rear derailleur, as those are both 10 speed they will work together.

Those will not work with a R7000 series *11 speed* cassette. Even if you thought you could just select 10 sprockets out of the  11 that does not work. Sprocket spacing is different between 10 and 11 speeds.

Also the HG CN-6701 chain is 10 speed specific and would not work properly on an 11 speed cassette.

Get a 10 speed cassette to make this setup work.

Comment: Thank you for this info I really appreciate your help. I’ll change the cassette and update this thread. Cheers.

Comment: A 10 speed cassette is the "fiscally-responsible" choice, but OP could also change the right-hand shifter to an 11 speed model (and put up with a mismatch between the two levers),  the rear derailleur mech, and the chain to an 11 speed width.  This would be more expensive though.

Comment: @Criggie i was curious if it was even possible to get a single Shimano road shifter, so I googled. it may be possible if the OP wanted this, it should be just as expensive to change both shifters. Although, single levers might pop up on eBay. That said, It might be easier to find a single right GRX lever because many GRX users will want a 1x setup.

Comment: @WeiwenNg Fair point - My LBS stocks individual shifters and matched pairs, but I'm more likely to buy a good-used part from auction or the local bike wreckers.

Comment: Update: I changed my cassette to a 10 speed as instructed. I’m having the same behaviour on a few gears. I tried adjusting the cable tension, nothing is working. Any other suggestions? Thank you